# jQuery combining checkbox values to modify output

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/qum7n8Lt/

I'd like to make it so only the classes with ALL of the checked items are displayed, instead of only requiring a single one.

```
$(".wpbdp-listing:visible").hide();
checkedboxes.each(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).val()).closest('.wpbdp-listing').show();
});
```

At the moment if you select "Color" and "Custom" it will show results that contain EITHER color OR custom. I'd like it to only show results that contain both color AND custom.

Comment: did not understand what you are asking?

Comment: are you trying to implement similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/k3965fr5/1/

Comment: At the moment if you select "Color" and "Custom" it will show results that contain EITHER color OR custom. I'd like it to only show results that contain both color AND custom.

Comment: please check my answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below changes in `ToggleThings` function, where you need to make list of value of checked check box and then use it as jQuery selector to find the `div`

```
function ToggleThings()
{

    var checkedboxes = $("#filters :checkbox:checked");

    if(checkedboxes.length > 0)
    {
        $(".wpbdp-listing:visible").hide();
        //create a string of '.' (dot) preceded class name list
        var classess = '';     
        checkedboxes.each(function() {
            classess+='.' + $(this).val();
        });
        //use class string to find all div
        $(classess).closest('.wpbdp-listing').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".wpbdp-listing").show();
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qum7n8Lt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple classes like this:

`$(".class1.class2.class3.class545645").doWhatYouWant();`

So you can create such a selector for your classes in your `.each()`:

```
var selector = "";
checkedboxes.each(function(){
    selector += "."+$(this).val();
});
```

Now you can show the items with this selector:

```
$(selector).closest('.wpbdp-listing').show();
```

Comment: That's not the same thing...your 'selector' would only work if the element had all those classes...and I don't think that's what is being asked for.